# No option for C++ in Qt Creator (for project)

Tags: qt, c++, qt-creator, qt5, qmake

I've installed the Qt 5.4.0 for Linux 64-bit (542 MB) on gnome ubuntu 14.04,
When I started new project, I couldn't find the "Qt C++ Application" tab.
There is option for C,QT,BLACKBERY....... But no c++ option.

Here is screenshot:-
[image]

[image]

Please help.

Comment: I thought Qt natively used some variant of C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was created due to fonts :P I changed fonts setting from gnome tool, due to which '+' sign was not showing. And my projects was not working because my collage uses old version of qt and i have latest one so i need to convert it. After changing font to' sans' no i can see c++ option :P :P , and i edited code to latest one now pojects are working.